# How do I prevent CiviSMS from converting my URLs to longer clickthrough-aware URLs?

Tags: civimail, sms

CiviMail and CiviSMS both default to tracking click-throughs.  To do so, it converts a link like `http://www.cnn.com` to something much longer, like `https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=91701&qid=2521100`.  That's fine in CiviMail, when you a) can turn it off, and b) you can hide it behind a hyperlink - but it can be really annoying in a text message.

Since there's no "track click-throughs" checkbox when creating an SMS, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You can install this extension: https://github.com/PalanteJon/coop.palantetech.nosmsurltracking.  This will automatically turn off click-through tracking on all mass SMS messages.  There's no checkbox (unless someone codes one in), so it turns tracking off on ALL messages - but if you need tracking on a single message, you can disable the extension temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use https:// my Android phone recognizes it as a link and makes it hyperlinked.

On Civi 5.23.4