# Is there a way to generate a click-through report from a Mass SMS?

Tags: sms, civisms, click-through

Unlike [How do I prevent CiviSMS from converting my URLs to longer clickthrough-aware URLs?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/9921/5446), I'd like to take advantage of clickthrough tracking in mass SMS's. The links in the SMS message are replaced with what looks to me like a clicktrhoough tracker (e.g. https://***/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=47&qid=3010) but I can't find any mass SMS in the Mail Clickthroughs report. I can't even find the destination URL in MySql's civicrm_mailing_trackable_url.